# SQLAlchemy - Performing AND operation , Combining 'like' and 'in_'

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write an SQLAlchemy query.

There is AND operation is needed to be performed as well as I need to know the way of Combining 'like' and 'in_' of SQLALchemy.

I tried the query as follows:

```
query = query.filter(and_(model.tenant_id.in_(tenant_ids) , model.name.like(ips)))
```

Here what I need is way to achieve combination of "in" and "like" of SQLAlchemy.

Following section is the one which I need to apply "in" and "like".

```
model.name.like(ips)
```

Consider ips field is an list, It contains following data.

```
['1.6.7.1']
```

I need to apply % before and after the same.

How can I do this.?

We cant apply like this here.

```
model.data.like(%ips%)
```

So some one let me know the solution for the same.

Comment: Please clarify your last sentence. What does "working" mean in your context?

Comment: Could you please have a look at the question now.I edited it now.

Comment: It seems you are doing it the right way. What's the problem? What do you expect to get and what do you actually get? Remember you have te use the wildcard symbols `%` and `?` in your like expression. For instance, `ips = u'%foo%'`

Comment: Please make sure `tenant_ids` will not be empty. Some databases have unintuitive behaviour if they do a `LIKE` on an empty sequence.